# Size of bar chart area compared to whole chart area

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

My bar charts does not take up the space in the whole chart area that I want to it to. The space between the bar chart and the legends to the right seems way to wide. I have not found any controls to adjust this. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: You can manually control all those locations setting both `ChartAreas` and `Legends` `Position` property.

Comment: What did you tweak to create this effect? By default the automatic positioning should work without any changes..

Comment: @Jimi Thanks! It did not solve it perfectly, but it was 73% by default, and increasing to 80-85% did wonders!

Comment: @TaW I just stretched it, I'm a bit surprised how bad it behaved myself.

Comment: _I just stretched it_ Meaning what?? Can you show the code? Once you mess with any of the sizes the automatic will be off. I would try to reset it; any Position you set manually tends to look less good once you chart changes, e.g. because it was anchored or docked..